# QScopedpointer fails at Q_DISABLE_COPY

Tags: c++, qt, copy-constructor

I use `QScopedPointer` for a class that is derived from `QObject`.

`MainWindow` contains it as:

```
private:
    QScopedPointer<CalculationManager> calculationManager;
```

In the constructor this however fails:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    calculationManager(QScopedPointer<CalculationManager>(new CalculationManager()))
```

In the line of `qscopedpointer.h`:

```
Q_DISABLE_COPY(QScopedPointer)
```

With:

```
C:\Qt\5.7\mingw53_32\include/QtCore/qscopedpointer.h: In constructor 'MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget*)':
C:\Qt\5.7\mingw53_32\include/QtCore/qscopedpointer.h:176:20: error: 'QScopedPointer<T, Cleanup>::QScopedPointer(const QScopedPointer<T, Cleanup>&) [with T = CalculationManager; Cleanup = QScopedPointerDeleter<CalculationManager>]' is private
     Q_DISABLE_COPY(QScopedPointer)
                    ^
```

Why and where does the copy take place?

Answer (score 4):

`QScopedPointer` has not a move constructor.
Because of that, if you consider this line:

```
calculationManager(QScopedPointer<CalculationManager>(new CalculationManager()))
```

Here a temporary object of type `QScopedPointer<CalculationManager>` is constructed and then copied over to `calculationManager` data member.
You can do this to avoid that extra copy:

```
calculationManager(new CalculationManager())
```

It will invoke the constructor that expects a pointer to a `CalculationManager` and no copy will take place.